# How to install SDL_bgi having SDL2 installed without Xcode (edit: with Xcode)

Tags: terminal, xcode, homebrew, graphics

I would like to install **SDL_bgi** on macOS without Xcode. I’ve downloaded the file

• Sources: SDL_bgi-2.4.0.tar.gz

from the website [sourceforge](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net). But now that I have the folder,
[image]I don’t know how to install it. I have tried running `sh /path/to/file` but I get the following message:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Maelle:~ mae.jml$ sh /Users/mae.jml/Downloads/SDL_bgi-2.4.0/build.sh 
cat: VERSION: No such file or directory
/Users/mae.jml/Downloads/SDL_bgi-2.4.0/build.sh: line 6: cmake: command not found

*** I don't know what package to build.
```

Is it because I am not in the right directory where SDL2 is installed?

For now I have installed SDL2 without Xcode following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@edkins.sarah/set-up-sdl2-on-your-mac-without-xcode-6b0c33b723f7). That means I currently have my game project folder, and inside it **lib** and **include** folders containing the SDL2 necessary files.

Maybe that is the problem, do I need Xcode?

I would like to use other graphic libraries more modern but my school is making it mandatory for us to use BGI. I really need to get it installed on my Mac.

## EDIT

I have downloaded Xcode and installed SDL2 with the dmg (moved framework to /library/frameworks). I tried compiling with the header `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`. It is compiling but I did include it in the Xcode settings, like so:
[image: Xcode configuration]
I have succeeded to follow the steps in INSTALL.md which are:

1. Unarchive the Sources file
2. cd to the newly unarchived folder
3. run `./build.sh`

It created the build folder. The next step was to run `sudo make install` in the new build folder, it returns this error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target SDL_bgi
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/SDL_bgi.dir/src/SDL_bgi.c.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-s' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from /Users/mae.jml/Downloads/SDL_bgi-2.4.0/src/SDL_bgi.c:35:
/Users/mae.jml/Downloads/SDL_bgi-2.4.0/src/SDL_bgi.h:34:10: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file
      not found
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SDL_bgi.dir/src/SDL_bgi.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SDL_bgi.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Which is weird since I do have SDL2, it is compiling in Xcode! Maybe I should move the directory to where SDL2 is installed but that seems unnecessary.

I have tried the other way which is moving manually the files:

`SDL_bgi.h`        -> `/library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers`

`graphics.h`       -> `/usr/include/`

`libSDL_bgi.so`    -> `/usr/lib/`

But I can’t find the third file.
Can anyone help?